# How to run query apply long text as a condition

Tags: php, mysql

Table Name service and row name service name

### service_name (col type -text)

Software Development (Including Feasibility Study, System Analysis & Design and Coding)

I ran a query collect service_name

```
$query_3="SELECT * from service  where service_name='Software Development (Including Feasibility Study, System Analysis & Design and Coding)' ";

$result_3=mysql_query($query_3) or die (mysql_error());
$row_3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_3);

$service=$row_3['service_name'];

echo $service;
```

When I run this query my query run successfully but result show empty.

But when i run query using small text query run successfully and result show.

Please, anyone can tell me what's the problem and How can I solve this problem

Comment: You have asked some questions and got good answers, but have not accepted any of them. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are no entries in the `service1 table with the`service_name` matching the service name you are specifying.

I would verify that the service_name that you are inputting is correct, and that you have entries in the table.  I would go to your db shell and type `SELECT count(*) from service` to verify there are entries.

If there are results I would then do something like `SELECT * from service where service_name LIKE %Development%` or some general query like that just to make sure that the row you are looking for exists.

If it does exist I would then look to make sure the service_name you are inputting is an exact match of the service name in the database.  Make sure spaces are correct, cases, everything.